# AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'get_nearest_node'

Tags: streamlit, osmnx

Can someone explain to me why I am told that AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'get_nearest_node' when I run my streamlit application?
I have installed scipy and scikit-learn.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/69392846/7321942

Answer (score 2):

`get_nearest_node()` was removed from OSMnx in [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/e104ce94f6f9ebfe43c65342e33169fefa09f112/CHANGELOG.md#110-2021-05-01).

The most similar function which is still available is [osmnx.nearest_nodes()](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html?highlight=nearest_node#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes). However, it is slightly different and you should read the documentation to understand how.